# Migrate wordpress site from IIS to Apache

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to migrate my existing wordpress site hosted in IIS to Apache. Is there any steps to follow or we need to completely install new wordpress and develop.

Comment: No need to install new wordpress if move wordpress site from IIS to Apache. just copy everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please copy your project files all over. The only issue that will see would be your permalink structure. so note your Permalinks structure.

Now you need to check the WordPress Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks and saved your existing settings there. And it's done.

You can get more help from [here](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2010/02/moving-from-iis-to-apache-it-easier.html).